# Unexpected time.sleep() behaviour

Tags: python, python-3.x, performance, time, sleep

Recently, when creating a loop with a very short wait at the end, I ran into an unexpected behaviour of `time.sleep()` when used in quick succession.

I used this piece of code to look further into my problem

```
import time
import statistics

def average_wait(func):
    waits=[]
    loops=0

    while loops<1000:
            start=time.time()
            func(1/1000)
            waits.append(time.time()-start)
            loops+=1
    print(waits)
    print("Average wait for 0.001: {}".format(statistics.mean(waits)))

average_wait(time.sleep)
```

This function usually returns something around 0.0013 which is many many times less accurate than just calling `time.sleep()` once, upon further inspection of this problem by looking at the `waits` list, I found that the amount of time `time.sleep()` was actually sleeping for was either almost exactly the right amount of time or almost exactly double the amount of time.

Here is a sample from `waits`: 
`[0.0010008811950683594, 0.0020041465759277344, 0.0009999275207519531, 0.0019621849060058594, 0.0010418891906738281]`

Is there any reason for this behaviour and anything that can be done to avoid it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [`time.time()` documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#time.time):

> Note that even though the time is always returned as a floating point number, not all systems provide time with a better precision than 1 second.

The precision is platform dependent. Moreover, it produces wall-clock time, and your process is never the only thing running on a modern OS, other processes *also* are given time to process and you'll see variation in timings in your own process because of that.

The module offers different clocks, with more precision and some are per-process. See the [`time.get_clock_info()` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#time.get_clock_info) to see what precision they offer. Note [`time.process_time()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#time.process_time) offers per-process time but excludes sleep time.

Next, `time.sleep()` is also not going to sleep in exact time spans; again from the [relevant documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#time.sleep):

> [T]he suspension time may be longer than requested by an arbitrary amount because of the scheduling of other activity in the system.

It too is subject to OS scheduling.

Together, these effects can easily add up to the millisecond variation in timings you see in your experiments. So this is not a doubling of time slept; even if you used different values for `time.sleep()` you'd still see a similar deviation from the requested time.

Comment: I'm using Windows 10 and I can confirm that the precision offered by time.sleep is definitely better than 1 second so that isn't the problem, as for other processes being allocated processing time. I understand this however I would assume that this would just add a small element of randomness, however in this situation the small deviation is not the problem rather the HUGE deviation of sometimes randomly being double

Comment: @froog: you are dealing in milliseconds here. It is absolutely possible for other processes to be active for a millisecond before the OS returns control to your process.

Comment: @froog If you're on Windows, it also has a pretty extreme and variable CPU throttling approach in some power settings, even if you're on a PC and not a laptop. Go into Control Panel --> Power Options and check that it's set at High Performance (at least in Windows 7 that was the way). Not having unrestricted CPU performance can mess up `timeit` too giving very variable results.

Comment: I see what you mean now, I was thinking of it as the time being doubled instead of an extra millisecond being added on, I'll try it again with 1/100 and 1/10 of a second and see if the results are repeated

Comment: @froog: I'd not count on sleep being that precise. And note that the [`time.sleep()` documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#time.sleep) warns: *Also, the suspension time may be longer than requested by an arbitrary amount because of the scheduling of other activity in the system*.

Comment: @froog: Python isn't exactly known for it's suitability for exact timings, but unless you are running a dedicaded realtime OS, you can't get precise timings in other programming languages *either* due to process switching and other scheduled tasks and interrupts that the kernel has to process.